# Conducting a training seminar without projector

Tags: presentation, seminars, training

What is the best way to conduct a training seminar inside a computer laboratory without a projector?

Is there an existing software program that could achieve the same results as conducting a training seminar with the aid of a projector?

Comment: Are you using existing material designed for a projector,or are do you need to design your own (and prefer software over a projector)?

Comment: there is an existing, but i could do with software over projector

Comment: Whiteboard markers?

Comment: Hehehe nice one @JeffE, sorry forgot to mention no, whiteboard.

Comment: Is there a window? Alternatively, can you spend $50 at Staples and buy your own whiteboard?

Answer (score 2):

Put your seminar material online, and just have people view it at the same time as you talk. It can be any easily readable format, like PDF file or simply series of web pages. If you are not sure that people will follow, just put large bold numbers on each page, and announce what page you're at when you change page. (A bit like kids' audio book!)

Either that, or hard copies of the material.

Comment: I think were on the same page, but is there an online to allow me to change which slide they are looking at by changing my slides? is it possible?

Comment: Why would you want to? (I assume your students are adults.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I get the situation:

Does "no projector" (and no whiteboard) mean

- You do not want to use a projector (nor a whiteboard)?
  => IMHO you should then know what you want (and tell us why), without that we'll not know what to answer
- Or: just there is no projector available
  => borrow projector somewhere
- or is it no possibity to project to a suitable space
  => borrow projector and screen,
- no possibility for placing a screen, neithr
  => or go for a different room?

Answer (score 0):

CLI or GUI? If GUI, you can have everyone watch your screen w/ a remote desktop client. Other solutions for CLI too (screen program) but I guess you're using a GUI.

Comment: more or less the same idea, but i need something that does not require to be installed. Is there a web-based solution that could have the same results?

Comment: Never used it myself, but I think [Big Blue Button](http://www.bigbluebutton.org/overview/) does what you want.

Comment: Not installed on your or their computer? I think all OS have clients. You might need to install the server, but even that I don't think so. This is a user-level default software solution.